install failed with office in playonlinux
I'm trying to install office using Playonlinux but got this error every time i setup the copy with installing the .NET framework

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Didn't know that there was an "installable" Office anymore. It moved to office 365 which is only available for windoze. Check Playonlinux which versions of that spyware is supported.
Having an office license that stuff can be used via a browser.

@guiverc  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

@kanehekili do you mean that i will not able to install office 2010 that i already have it

Not with a windows XP dot net. Windows XP is dead! Look at your URL. I'd advise you to get a VirtualBox and install a Windows 7 as a guest. There is no sane reason to install XP files nowadays. Besides: There are better open source office packages (libreOffice or freeoffice) that run on Linux native.

@guiverc Why should it matter at all whether OP Is using Ubuntu desktop or Ubuntu Server with a GUI (as you can see from the screenshot)? If an answer requires certain dependencies, then the answer should mention it.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Ubuntu Server & Ubuntu Desktop have different defaults; and if the desktop is installed using flavor metapackages the defaults can differ to a Server install that had GUI installed via metapackages imported from upstream Debian.  Those differences are the exception rather than a rule, but clear details of what is being used allow for far more accurate answers.

@guiverc how can i know if it desktop or server please

You choose which you're using at download time; you'll almost certainly be using a Desktop system as the Server release is text only (ie. no graphical user interface or GUI; the Desktop system includes a GUI/desktop..).  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop includes the GNOME Desktop, or GNOME GUI on top of the base 22.04 system...  Server installs are usually used on headless machines in racks or away from users including in the cloud; where as a Desktop install has a monitor, keyboard & mouse as is used by a user near the machine

Please try this https://www.ubuntumint.com/install-microsoft-office-ubuntu/
